# Is the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-|x|}$ convex?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Is $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-|x|}, x\in \mathbb{R}$ convex?

Since $f''(x)=-\dfrac{2}{\left(\left|x\right|-1\right)^3}$, we can't claim $f''(x) > 0$ for all x. So $f(x)$ is not convex. But on page 56, Yurii Nesterov's Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization: A Basic Course claimed that $f(x)$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$. Note that $f(x)$ is not even defined for $x=1$. Did I miss something?

Comment: what is $R$, is it the same as $\mathbb R$? (`$\mathbb R$`)

Comment: I think that the claim is that $f$ is convex on $R=(-1,1)$...probably

Comment: It is true in $x \in (-1,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint/verification. [(Desmos link)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/re3tisleng)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right indeed for $x>0$ we have

$$f(x)=g(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x}\implies g''(x)=-\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}$$

and since $f(x)$ is even we have that it is convex for $x\in(-1,1)$.